# Debian Buster fsck failed with exit status 4

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, startup, fstab

I posted this already somewhere else but didn't get any response.

I have updated my raspberry pi from Jessie to Buster now
since then I finally was able to get domoticz working again, but another problem came up.

when I plug in the raspberry it starts up but not completely.

It says emergency mode with the message

```
can not access to console, the root account is locked
press enter to continue
```

I press enter and PI just starts up and everything works.

The problem is that normally I never have a keyboard or display connected.

So i need it to start completely like it did for the last 5 years.

i found a couple of faults in log including this

```
fsck failed with exit status 4
failed to start file system Check on root device
```

found a lot of treads but can not find a solution

```
sudo fsck -f
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

       cat  /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

hope this might be a fist direction of what i can find but im a noob so dont know what to do further

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a general rule, cross-posting of a question is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). In order to help us assess whether the question can be left here, please edit your question to provide a link to the other post you made.

Answer (score 0):

You can have tune2fs do a fsck on boot with the following command

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

This tells the system to do a fsck every reboot on the root / device. 
Almost forgot to say, then reboot it should fsck /. 
Note this will only work on ext2/3/4 filesystems

You can see last date for fsck with the following

```
tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p2 |grep -i "last checked"
```